# Sed flag is not working

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have 3000 words that are repeated (ARG ARG ARG ARG ....)

I am trying to search and replace the 500th word by 'UIO'

I have been trying it with `sed -i 's/ARG/UIO/500' filename.txt`

I have also tried it with `sed -i 's/ARG/UIO/500g' filename.txt` but it does not work.

I does not report any mistake but it doesn't change anything in `filename.txt` either.

What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Are the words all on the same line? Sed restarts its count every time it gets a newline.

Comment: I just tested this by creating a file with 3000 repetitions of `ARG` and `sed 's/ARG/UIO/500'` worked exactly as expected. So something is different in your case. Please post an example of your input file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Add the `-z` option to make it do it on the 500th occurrence in the file as opposed to the 500th occurrence of each line (assuming the file doesn't contain NUL characters and a recent enough version of GNU `sed`).

Comment: The flag is working exactly as intended, as @JosephSible implies.  Suggest using Perl in paragraph mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the words are distributed over lines you could do (as portable solution)

```
sed -i 'H;1h;$!d;g;s/ARG/UIO/500' filename.txt
```

to collect lines in the hold space first and finally do the replacement with all lines in the same buffer.